# SQL Server Management Studio Issues

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I accidentally deleted YEARS of data in SQL Server Management Studio from a table. Unfortunately the person in this position before me didn't back anything up. Nor did I before I tried to fix an issue. I understand that it cannot be retrieved from SQL but I have all the data I need in a separate file on my desktop. Is their anyway to get that data and input it back into the table that is in SQL? Or is there a query I can run to input the data again into the table? I'm not sure if I am making any sense :/

Comment: Yes it's possible ... there are many ways to import data into SQL Server. What type of file do you have?

Comment: Honestly I can't be sure. The program that we use to get the information is called Document Direct, it puts the information into the SQL Server and then that info gets put into a table in Access. The files from Document Direct are backed up into one massive file but I'm not sure how to get them to go back into SQL Server and if I will then be able to make the table that is in SQL to get the data back into the way that it was. Is this making sense?

Answer (score 1):

You can also used Management Studio without SSIS. Right click on the database in MS and select Tasks -> Import Data. You should then be able to select the type of source (flat file) and the format. The rest of the wizard is pretty self-explanatory.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a flat file like .txt or .csv or even an Excel file like(.xls), you can build an SSIS package and dump the data to a new table. Depends, on what kind of data you have in your hand.

Comment: Honestly I can't be sure. The program that we use to get the information is called Document Direct, it puts the information into the SQL Server and then that info gets put into a table in Access. The files from Document Direct are backed up into one massive file but I'm not sure how to get them to go back into SQL Server and if I will then be able to make the table that is in SQL to get the data back into the way that it was. Is this making sense?

Comment: Yeah unfortunately I don't think it is a flat file :/ I tried the route you suggested with no luck. I won't show me the files when I go to the folder. Can I not do anything with these then? I'm not sure what the point of backing them up in such a way would do. Especially if you cannot use them?

Comment: Yeah! It makes sense. You sure it's a backup file? If it is in some other format, which SQL Server or SSIS can't detect, you may have to transform it. Else, try that tool "Document Direct" and see if any restore option is there in it. If it is backing up the data, then it may have a restore option too.

Comment: Hey thank you so much for your help! I am able to pull exactly what I want with the help of a macro in Access. Fortunately it was already there and I will just have to alter it to retrieve the data that I need. Again thank you so much!